# Read -> Consume -> Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I'm using producer - many consumers pattern.

Database has records in place already.

1. Producer reads records and put them into thread-safe queue.
2. Consumer threads process records one-by-one and add more data to it.
3. Now producer has to update records in database with new data provided by consumers.

I'm new with Entity Framework and do not know what approach to use in order to update those records properly.

I've read that I can select a List of records from db, edit fields directly to it and then simply call `SaveChanges` on context object. But I doubt that some of consumer will be in the middle of editing some of the properties from the List.

Comment: why can't the consumers update the database?

Comment: Can they? I'm not sure it is good to update db with the same context from myltiple threads. Reading EF Documentation.. I was hoping to get a quick advice on best practice in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  The first example shows how to update a single record, the second shows how to update with a list of records. You can add or delete data you want from any of the object in the list as long as they are of a type in your data model.  Then call up your db context and iterate through each of the objects in the list.  Update the database with SaveChanges().

```
    public List<Customer> MyCustomers { get; set; }

    public void GetCustomers()
    {
        using(var context = new SalesContext())
        {
            var customers = from b in context.Customers
                            select b;

            MyCustomers = customers.ToList<Customer>();
        }
    }

    public void MethodThatChangesCustomers()
    {

    }

    public void UpdateDatabase()
    {
        using(var context = new SalesContext())
        {
            foreach (var person in MyCustomers)
            {
                context.Customers.Add(person);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But, seems like you didn't read my question... I want to read a few records in queue, let consumers add data to it, and then update it back to database.

Comment: When you say queue are you referring to objects that were pulled from the database into an IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: Yes, correct. Pulled into enumerable and then converted to List<T> by calling ToList()